# How to run a fixed number of processes in a loop?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, wait

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i=1 to 200000
do
create input file
run ./java
done
```

I need to run a number (8 or 16) of processes (java) at the same time and I don't know how. I know that `wait` could help but it should be running 8 processes all the time and not wait for the first 8 to finish before starting the other 8.

Comment: [Using GNU parallel](https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/).

Answer (score 8):

`bash` 4.3 added a useful new flag to the `wait` command, `-n`, which causes `wait` to block until *any* single background job, not just the members of a given subset (or all), to complete.

```
#!/bin/bash
cores=8  # or 16, or whatever
for ((i=1; i <= 200000; i++))
do
    # create input file and run java in the background.
    ./java &

    # Check how many background jobs there are, and if it
    # is equal to the number of cores, wait for anyone to
    # finish before continuing.
    background=( $(jobs -p) )
    if (( ${#background[@]} == cores )); then
        wait -n
    fi
done
```

There is a small race condition: if you are at maximum load but a job completes *after* you run `jobs -p`, you'll still block until another job
completes. There's not much you can do about this, but it shouldn't present too much trouble in practice.

---

Prior to `bash` 4.3, you would need to poll the set of background jobs periodically to see when the pool dropped below your threshold.

```
while :; do
    background=( $(jobs -p))
    if (( ${#background[@]} < cores )); then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GNU Parallel` like this, simplified to 20 jobs rather than 200,000 and the first job is `echo` rather than *"create file"* and the second job is `sleep` rather than *"java"*.

```
seq 1 20 | parallel -j 8 -k 'echo {}; sleep 2'
```

The `-j 8` says how many jobs to run at once. The `-k` says to keep the output in order.

Here is a little animation of the output so you can see the timing/sequence:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a non-ancient version of GNU utilities or on *BSD/OSX, use [`xargs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&sektion=1) with the `-P` option to run processes in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash
seq 200000 | xargs -P 8 -n 1 mytask
```

where `mytask is an auxiliary script, with the sequence number (the input line) available as the argument`$1`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Task number $1"
create input file
run ./java
```

You can put everything in one script if you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
seq 200000 | xargs -P 8 -n 1 sh -c '
  echo "Task number $1"
  create input file
  run ./java
' mytask
```

If your system doesn't have `seq`, you can use the bash snippet

```
for ((i=1; i<=200000; i++)); do echo "$i"; done
```

or other shell tools such as

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=200000; i++) print i}' </dev/null
```

or

```
</dev/zero tr '\0' '\n' | head -n 200000 | nl
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up 8 subprocesses that read from a common stream; each subprocess reads one line of input and starts a new job whenever its current job completes.

```
forker () {
    while read; do
        # create input file
        ./java
    done
}

cores=8 # or 16, or whatever
for ((i=1; i<=200000; i++)); do
    echo $i
done | while :; do
    for ((j=0; j< cores; j++)); do
         forker &
    done
done
wait   # Waiting for the $core forkers to complete
```